# using cookies in cURL with php

Tags: php, curl, cookies, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a shopping website which shows pricing in different currency.

There is an drop down box to choose a currency type which calls the following line `http://www.xxxx.com/find/setCurrency.jsp?code=INR`

after clicking it redirects to its parent page. If I clear the cookie the prices are are back in USD

I am working with `cURL` in `PHP` and `simple_html_dom` to scrape the products. How can I find which cookie is responsible for the action and how can I use cookies in cURL

Comment: This isn't quite clear - are you wanting to use cookies on the remote site, or on your site? Can you explain your intent more clearly?

Comment: It's pretty clear to me. How can you know? You'd have to reverse engineer it. Try to set the different cookie values that was set with your browser. Besides that I guess the only thing left is to ask them. And it's scrape, not scrap.

Comment: @dan-klasson most of the cookies have hash values so i couldn't guess it out.

Comment: What about if you change your browser's locale? Does it still show USD as default?

Comment: yes it still shows USD as default

Comment: @dan-klasson can you please look at the link that i have commented in the karmendra's answer so that you can help me better

Comment: Don't think that helps much. It seems that your problem is that the cookies are random, so you don't know what cookies to use. My take is that you might need to find another angle, or give up on it.

Comment: Could you please clarify me that if i set a cookie in curl and i run that php in browser with xampp, will the cookie inspecter shows the cookie created via curl?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69454/discussion-between-dharanbro-and-dan-klasson).

Comment: Yeah it could. Check out `--cookie`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Goolge Chrome extension [Cookie Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-inspector/jgbbilmfbammlbbhmmgaagdkbkepnijn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) to view add delete cookies.

To find the one that is responsible for currency open that site, clear all cookies using the inspector, select the currency and see what cookie is set now.

Hope this helps

Comment: That makes it difficult then, try removing cookies one by one and reload the page observer see what effects the currency. or copy all cookies to one place and add one by one observer what changes the currency.

Comment: May I know what site are you trying this on?